# How to add Multiple validation rule

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, validation, customer-address, form-validation

I have to add three validation rule and as you see below code works well for one rule :
**validation-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    console.log('this is own');
    return function (validator) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'myvalidation',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                
                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('myvalidation')
        );
        return validator;
    }
});
```

I searched the site questions and does not find a question something like this.

Is any way to add more validation rules in magento2 with out override rules.Js file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use more times `addMethod` and add more rules in the same mixin.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    
    return function (validator) {

        $.validator.addMethod(
            'firstvalidation',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here

                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('myvalidation')
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            'secondvalidation',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here

                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Second validation')
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            'nextvalidation',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here

                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Hey, I am next :)')
        );

        return validator;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You Works with charm!!
Like Benz ;)